# Duda en controlador laravel con php

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un problema con el controlador, Busco un producto y a la vez busco un producto que tengo relacionado hasta aqui no tengo problema uso este controlador:

```
 public function show($id)
        {

            $producto = Producto::find($id);
            $relacionado = relaciones::where('idrelacion', $id)->find();




            return view('products.show', compact('producto', 'relacionado'));
        }
```

Pero cuando intento buscar el producto relacionado en la tabla base me da el error siguiente error :**Property [parentesco_id] does not exist on this collection instance.** "pero en la tabla relaciones si existe parentesco_id"
Este es el controlador que uso:

```
 public function show($id)
  {

                $producto = Producto::find($id);
                $relacionado = relaciones::where('idrelacion', $id)->find();
                $productorecomendado = Producto::where('id', $relacionado->producto_id)-->find();



                return view('products.show', compact('producto', 'productorecomendado'));
            }
```

Como puedes ver lo que intento es volver a buscar en la tabla productos con el id que me arroja la variable relacionado pero no lo consigo..

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado cambie `Find()` por `First()` y la forma de escribir la variable `$relacionado->producto_id` por `$relacionado['producto_id']`.

```
public function show($id)
  {

                $producto = Producto::find($id);
                $relacionado = relaciones::where('idrelacion', $id)->first();
                $productorecomendado = Producto::where('id', $relacionado[producto_id])->get();

                return view('products.show', compact('producto', 'productorecomendado'));
            }
```

Comment: recuerda que no es solo poner el código, debes explicarlo para que el resto de usuarios sepamos que arreglaste

Comment: además yo sigo viendo un error en tu código aqui `-->` no se si asi lo estas usando pero la flechita es con un solo guió bajo y ahi pusiste 2 entonces este código que pones no debería funcionar

Comment: Perdona ahora mismo lo explico. no lo estoy usando es un error al escribirlo aquí